# How can I get permanent 5.1 sound?

Tags: sound

I have a Lenovo Ideapad y510 with 5.1 sound and worked perfectly on Windows.

I read a guide to get 5.1 sound on Ubuntu which proposes to do the following.

Edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and change the `default-sample-channels` from 2 to 6.

Then edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base` and add the line

```
options snd-hda-intel model=3stack-6ch-dig
```

and restart the system.

After the first reboot the sound works perfectly, but when I power off or restart the machine the sound does not work.

How can I make those changes permanent?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the sound profile the normal way first. Click the little speaker icon at the top right of the desktop and choose 'Sound Settings...'. Click the Hardware tab in the window that comes up, and click on your audio device to configure. Then click on 'Profile:' and choose the profile you want, 5.1 in your case. You may have more than one 5.1 option, depending on your setup and motherboard outputs. Test that it works and then restart. The settings you changed should stick.

Answer (score 0):

I was too having trouble using 5.1 channels; this youtube video solved it for me:
 [How to setup ubuntu to use all surround sound speakers ...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeOuseUqe9Y)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. The shown solution seems to soundchip or soundcard specific. If one has this option, one might check it, but generally 5.1 sound should work.